# Let V the space vector of 2x2 matrices in IR. Let W be the subspace of symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I studied this subject a time ago, but now I have to answer this question. But the big problem is that my old exercises are different. I can't find a similar question on internet. Can you help me?

--
Let V the vector space of 2x2 matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$. Let  W be the subspace of symmetric matrices. Show that dim W = 3, determining a basis of W.

Can you help me? Should I use kernel?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Rather than thinking of $2\times 2$ matrices: $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ which are symmetric, you can think of the related question of vectors $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}$ if that helps you think.

**Additional hint:**

A symmetric $2\times 2$ matrix of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ must have $b=c$

Comment: Thank you. Is the solution like this? http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/cgi-bin/lat.cgi?cmd=bas;vdat=3;vdat=R4;m1_1=1;m2_1=0;m3_1=0;m4_1=0;m1_2=0;m2_2=1;m3_2=1;m4_2=0;m1_3=0;m2_3=0;m3_3=0;m4_3=1;curn=4;curn=3;whid=V;submit21=Submit&hideops=0

Comment: @user17245 Remember that the original question was written in terms of our space consisting of $2\times 2$ matrices... so your answer should also be written in terms of $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: I get it...thanks. But the calculator above is correct, should I only write in 2x2 matrices?

Answer (score 0):

Let $B_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}, B_2=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B_3=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Then each $B_j$ is symmetric. Show that $\{B_1,B_2,B_3\}$ is linearly independent and that $W=span (\{B_1,B_2,B_3\})$.

Comment: Thank you. Is the solution like this? http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/cgi-bin/lat.cgi?cmd=bas;vdat=3;vdat=R4;m1_1=1;m2_1=0;m3_1=0;m4_1=0;m1_2=0;m2_2=1;m3_2=1;m4_2=0;m1_3=0;m2_3=0;m3_3=0;m4_3=1;curn=4;curn=3;whid=V;submit21=Submit&hideops=0